# Not able to access a local git server

Tags: git, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, web-administration, bonobo

We have installed a bonobogit server by following this guide:
http://bonobogitserver.com/install/

I am able to access the repositories by using the web browser. I have created a XYZ repo using the browser. However when I try to clone it by using git-gui or command prompt, I get the following error:

> fatal: http://`localhost`/Bonobo.Git.Server/XYZ.git/info/refs not valid:
>   is this a git repository?

Comment: Do you have any branch on repo? Is `HEAD` valid ?

Comment: @prajmus we have a master branch. How to check if the head is valid?

Comment: Do you have any commits ? And also, in your server what's the authentication method set to ? Maybe it's a problem with it being windows, when you really want basic auth

Comment: No commits so far. There is no option to commit!

Comment: What should I do to check?

Comment: You can try creating a local repo with `git init` than `git add remote origin http://localhost/Bono.../GTD.git` than create a commit `git commit --allow-empty -m "Initial commit"` and push

Comment: @prajmus please check the question now

Comment: I made a mistake out of hurry, should be `git remote add ...` not `git add remote ...`

Comment: it says `fatal: remote origin already exists`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60005/discussion-between-prajmus-and-bubble).

Answer (score 2):

The problem in this case was resolved by setting the server for windows authentication as given in this [link](http://bonobogitserver.com/windows-authentication/).